# Jquery when checkbox is checked can't find closest inputs values

Tags: jquery

when i check checkbox i need get closest inputs value but no luck adding my code. Tried several combinations most of time undefined. Can someone tell me how correctly i can get those values? Maybe i need to create div to find those elements better? Then i need to slice those values and put in closest input with classname="barkodas".

```js
$(".skaiciuoja").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    var a = "";
    var b = "";
    var c = "";
    var d = "";
    a = $(this).closest('table').find('.A');
    b += $('.vaikai').closest(".B").find("input[name='b']").val();
    c += $('.vaikai').closest(".C").find("input[name='c']").val();
    d += $('.vaikai').closest(".D").find("input[name='d']").val();

    var atsakymas = a + b + c + d;


  }
  console.log(a);
  $(".barkodas").val(atsakymas);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="skaiciuoja" type="checkbox" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
<label for="skaiciuoja">Generuoti</label>
<br>
<table border="1">
  <tr class="vaikai">
    <td><input class="A bar" name="a" type="text" value="AAAA"></td>
    <td><input class="B bar" name="b" type="text" value="BBBB"></td>
    <td><input class="C bar" name="c" type="text" value="CCCC"></td>
    <td><input class="D bar" name="d" type="text" value="DDDD"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" style="background-color:yellow;height:50px;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><input class="barkodas" type="text" placeholder="Barkodas"></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br><br>
<br>
<input class="skaiciuoja" type="checkbox" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
<label for="skaiciuoja">Generuoti</label>
<br>
<table border="1">
  <tr class="vaikai">
    <td><input class="A bar" name="a" type="text" value="1111"></td>
    <td><input class="B bar" name="b" type="text" value="2222"></td>
    <td><input class="C bar" name="c" type="text" value="3333"></td>
    <td><input class="D bar" name="d" type="text" value="4444"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" style="background-color:yellow;height:50px;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><input class="barkodas" type="text" placeholder="Barkodas"></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Note that `.closest` doesn't mean "nearest" it specifically means the closest *parent* that matches the selector https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by searching for the adjacent table and find the inputs. Then concatenate the values.

See this example:

```js
$(".skaiciuoja").change(function() {
  // Find the frist table after this checkbox and get the inputs
  let input = $(this).nextAll("table:first").find("input.bar");
  
  // store display input to add/remove values
  let display = $(this).nextAll("table:first").find(".barkodas");

  if (this.checked) {
    let total = '';
    // Loop through inputs and concatenate the value
    input.each((i, e) => {
      total += e.value;
    });
    
    // Display and return so the rest of the code is not processed
    display.val(total);
    return;
  }
  // if not checked empty the input
  display.val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="skaiciuoja" type="checkbox" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
<label for="skaiciuoja">Generuoti</label>
<br>
<table border="1">
  <tr class="vaikai">
    <td><input class="A bar" name="a" type="text" value="AAAA"></td>
    <td><input class="B bar" name="b" type="text" value="BBBB"></td>
    <td><input class="C bar" name="c" type="text" value="CCCC"></td>
    <td><input class="D bar" name="d" type="text" value="DDDD"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" style="background-color:yellow;height:50px;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><input class="barkodas" type="text" placeholder="Barkodas"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br><br>
<br>
<input class="skaiciuoja" type="checkbox" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
<label for="skaiciuoja">Generuoti</label>
<br>
<table border="1">
  <tr class="vaikai">
    <td><input class="A bar" name="a" type="text" value="1111"></td>
    <td><input class="B bar" name="b" type="text" value="2222"></td>
    <td><input class="C bar" name="c" type="text" value="3333"></td>
    <td><input class="D bar" name="d" type="text" value="4444"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" style="background-color:yellow;height:50px;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><input class="barkodas" type="text" placeholder="Barkodas"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```